# lldb in Android Studio: select frame does not work

Tags: android, android-studio, lldb

I'm doing native debugging in Android Studio 1.5. The problem is that the lldb looks at the wrong frame (the bottom-most) and thus does not show me the correct register values.

```
select frame
```

Does not seem to have any effect:

> (lldb) bt
>       * thread #1: tid = 30637, 0x400e429e libc.so`strncpy, name = 'WHATEVER', stop reason = breakpoint 2.1
>           frame #0: 0x400e429e libc.so`strncpy
>         * frame #1: 0x406ba1b0 libicuuc.so
>       (lldb) frame info
>       frame #1: 0x406ba1b0 libicuuc.so
>
> ```
> (lldb) frame select 0
> frame #0: 0x400e429e libc.so`strncpy
> libc.so`strncpy:
> ->  0x400e429e <+0>: push   {r4, lr}
>     0x400e42a0 <+2>: cbz    r2, 0x400e42c4            ; <+38>
>     0x400e42a2 <+4>: subs   r1, #0x1
>     0x400e42a4 <+6>: mov    r3, r0
> (lldb) frame info
> frame #1: 0x406ba1b0 libicuuc.so
> (lldb) register read
> General Purpose Registers:
>         r4 = 0x40773ed4  
>         r5 = 0x407762a8  
>         r6 = 0x00000000
>         r7 = 0x40745eb0  
>         r8 = 0xbe9f2d30
>         r9 = 0xbe9f2b20
>        r10 = 0x400f8384  libc.so`__stack_chk_guard
>        r11 = 0x77205d00
>         sp = 0xbe9f2d30
>         lr = 0x406ba1b1  
>         pc = 0x75cdbd38
>       cpsr = 0x200b0030
> 5 registers were unavailable.
> ```

Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like Android Studio is resetting the frame after each command - probably to keep it in sync with what the UI is showing.  You selected frame 0, but then your frame info command, which should show frame 0's info, shows frame 1's instead.

If you select some frame in the Android Studio UI, and then do `frame info` in the console, does it show the frame you selected in the UI?  If that works then `register read` should also report the correct frame's registers, so you can use that as a work around for now.

If Android Studio has a bug reporter, you might file a bug about this issue.  lldb has support for keeping a UI and the command line in sync, but the UI has to adopt it.